# Kohana: Adapting Mixu's Auth Useradmin Template

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-auth

I'm looking at [Mixu's Auth module](http://blog.mixu.net/2010/09/14/kohana-3-auth-sample-implementation-and-documentation/) for Kohana 3.1 but want to implement the UI into my own site templates. At the moment my site runs properly using its own template until it gets to a restricted page. At that point it loads the useradmin module's template for logins. I'd like to just load the page components into my own template and navigation.

What is the best way to go about this please? I had imagined I would be able to arrest the flow at some point within my 'application' environment without editing the 'module' environment.

---

EDIT:
I'm a little further along now. I've created two Controller classes:

```
application/classes/controller/app.php
application/classes/controller/user.php
```

Each extends the module class and replaces the template reference. Eg:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct access allowed.');
    class Controller_User extends Useradmin_Controller_User {
        public $template = 'smarty:maintemplate';
    }
```

I guess this is the right approach. I'm using Smarty Templates which is compounding the issues as I need to merge different templates. I'll keep plugging away and see how I go.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the best way, but I had a similar situation.

In the end, I copied part of the code from the module that I needed, and rolled my own implementation of the module.

Btw. Smarty is ok, but [Kostache](https://github.com/zombor/KOstache) (Mustache for Kohana) rocks. More flexible and you can use the same templates for php and javascript.